# How to use SVM for People Recognition?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, svm, face-recognition

I'm running opencv 2.4.2 C++.

I'm trying to do people recognition using opencv.

I'm using the VidTIMIT dataset that contains different people in different orientation.

I'm using CvSVM to classify these people.

My problem is that svm's output is always the same.

The algorithm that I follow is:

1. face detection using Haar
2. resize of the face (58*58)
3. Svm Training
4. Classification

Now, I'm wondering if I did something wrong in the training.

I'm trying this method considering 5(num_name) person, 10(num_images) different images each.

```
void runFaceDetectionRecognition(vector<Mat_<uchar> > &images){
vector<vector<Rect> > faces;
for (unsigned i=0; i<images.size(); ++i) {

    /// detection face
    vector<Rect> f;
    faceDetection(images[i], f);

    if (!f.empty()) {
        faces.push_back(f);

        /// I keep only the face
        Mat_<uchar> roi = ( images[i](f[0]) );

        /// resize
        resize(roi, roi, Size(58, 58));

        roi.copyTo(images[i]);            
    }
}

/// Set up parameters
CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type    = CvSVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;
params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);


/// Set up training data
float labels[num_name][num_images];
float label = 0;

/// different label for different person
for (unsigned i=0; i<num_name; ++i) {
    for (unsigned j=0; j<num_images; ++j)
        labels[i][j] = label;

    label++;
}

/// labeling matrix
Mat labelsMat(num_name*num_images, 1, CV_32FC1, labels);

/// unrolling images
float data[images.size()][58*58];
for (unsigned l=0; l<images.size(); ++l)

    for (unsigned i=0; i<58; ++i)
        for (unsigned j=0; j<58; ++j)
            data[l][j+58*i] = images[l].at<float>(i,j);


/// training matrix
Mat train((int) images.size(),58*58, CV_32FC1, data);
CvSVM svm(train, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);

/// Validation
valSVM(svm, train.rowRange(0, 1));
}
```

The validation code:

```
void valSVM(CvSVM &svm, Mat train){

/// prediction
float response = svm.predict(train);

cout << "Response ===> " << response << " ";

/// output
if (response == 0)  cout << "lea";
else if (response == 1)  cout << "maria";
else if (response == 2)  cout << "ramona";
else if (response == 3)  cout << "teresa";
else if (response == 4)  cout << "yan";
}
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are training your SVMs with the full 58*58 face. In order for the SVM to work you need to reduce your dimensions (obtain your principal components) using a method like PCA (Principal Component Analysis) that is already included in OpenCV.

If you reduce your dimensions from a 58*58 array to a n*n array where n are the principal features, the training of the SVM will use only the principal features and will result in an improved solution.

There is a lot of documentation of face recognition with OpenCV, you can start [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceRecognition).

Answer (score 4):

The other answer here is not correct in saying that SVM must use PCA to function. I have used SVM on 128x128 images without PCA and achieved good results. I have done something similar with the cohn-kanade dataset. Here is some source code that may help out.

```
vector<Mat> preImages;//Fill this with your images from your dataset
vector<int> labels;//Fill this with the labels from the dataset
vector<Mat> images;

CascadeClassifier haar_cascade;
haar_cascade.load("/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
vector< Rect_<int> > faces;
Mat procFace;
cout << "images: " << preImages.size() << "    labels: " << labels.size() << endl;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < preImages.size(); i++)
{
    procFace = preImages[i].clone();
    //haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(procFace, faces);
    haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(
            procFace,
            faces,
            1.1,
            3,
            CASCADE_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT|CASCADE_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH,
            Size(110, 110)
    );

    if(faces.size() > 0)
    {

        // Process face by face:
        Rect face_i = faces[0];
        // Crop the face from the image.
        Mat face = procFace(face_i);

        ////You can maybe use the equalizeHist function here instead//////
        face = illuminationComp(face);

        //crop face
        Rect cropped(face_i.width*0.18, face_i.height*0.2, int(face_i.width*0.7), int(face_i.height*0.78));
        Mat Cface = face(cropped);

        Mat face_resized;
        resize(Cface, face_resized, Size(128, 128), 1.0, 1.0, INTER_CUBIC);

        images.push_back(face_resized);
    }
}


//svm parameters:
SVMParams params = SVMParams();
params.svm_type = SVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = SVM::LINEAR;
params.degree = 3.43; // for poly
params.gamma = 0.00225; // for poly / rbf / sigmoid
params.coef0 = 19.6; // for poly / sigmoid
params.C = 0.5; // for CV_SVM_C_SVC , CV_SVM_EPS_SVR and CV_SVM_NU_SVR
params.nu = 0.0; // for CV_SVM_NU_SVC , CV_SVM_ONE_CLASS , and CV_SVM_NU_SVR
params.p = 0.0; // for CV_SVM_EPS_SVR
params.class_weights = NULL; // for CV_SVM_C_SVC
params.term_crit.type = CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS;
params.term_crit.max_iter = 1000;
params.term_crit.epsilon = 1e-6;

if(images.size() == labels.size())
{
    cout << "Creating SVM Classification" << endl << endl;

    int rowsSize = images.size();
    int trainingArea = images[0].rows * images[0].cols;
    Mat trainingMat = Mat::zeros(rowsSize, trainingArea, CV_32FC1);
    int counter;


    for(int index = 0; index < rowsSize; index++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        for(int rows = 0; rows < images[0].rows; rows++)
        {
            for(int cols = 0; cols < images[0].cols; cols++)
            {
                trainingMat.at<float>(index, counter) = images[index].at<uchar>(rows,cols);
                    counter++;
            }
        }
    }


    Mat matLabels = Mat::zeros(labels.size(),1,CV_32FC1);
    for(size_t index = 0; index < labels.size(); index++)
    {
        matLabels.at<float>(index,0) = float(labels[index]);
    }

    if(trainingMat.rows == matLabels.rows)
    {
        SVM svm;
        svm.train(trainingMat,matLabels,Mat(),Mat(),params);
        svm.save("svm_model.yml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using raw image to train? It does not have feature extraction part. How about if I extract feature using LBP and use it as input of SVM train? Do I need convert the LBP feature to LBP histogram and train or not?

Comment: @user8430 : after you extracted lpb features, you need to calculate corresponding histogram, then pass that histogram vector to your svm classifier.

Comment: @user8430 yes, I used raw images to train. The only thing I did prior to training was run illumination equalization on the images and cropping/alignment.

Answer (score 0):

I am also building a project in which i have classify an object. I am using a combination of SVM and Bag of Features(BOf)/BOW. In this method first of all you create dictionary/codebook and then train your SVM. The results are quite good.

You ca have a look at this link to get an idea http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/08/25/a-simple-object-classifier-with-bag-of-words-using-opencv-2-3-w-code/